# separating a string that contains decimals and words and creating columns from the unique values in that string using Pandas/Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this string:

```
'Storage:9.22Checkoff:6.90InElevation:0.00OutCharge:0.00Freightother:0.00'
```

The first thing I need to do is separating values into the following form:

```
Storage:9.22 Checkoff:6.90 In_Elevation:0.00 Out_Charge:0.00 Freight_other:0.00
```

I will be looping through multiple rows with similar values, so I will have to make sure as soon as I see the name (and is unique) I create a new column and assign the value I found for that specific row, so at the end it should look something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Storage| Checkoff | In_Elevation | Out_Charge | Freight_other| 
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  9.22  |  6.90    |    0.00      |   0.00     |   0.00       |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've been using a couple of examples at least to start separating the string but it does not give me what I really need:

This is one:

```py
word = ""
value = ""
    
for i in  range(0, len(df['Original'])):
    for j in df['Original'][i]:
        if j.isalpha():
            word = word + j
        elif j.isdecimal():
            value = value + j
        elif j.isascii():
            #print(j)
            None
```

But this is the result:

```
StorageCheckoffInElevationOutChargeFreightotherStorageCheckoffMiscellaneousChargesPremiumFreightStorageCheckoffOptionPremiumsforMinimumPriceContractsFITRUCKDiscountsFORAILCarryCostStorageCheckoffFreightInElevationOutChargeFreightotherStorageCheckoffFreightWeighingChgsFORAILCheckoffInElevationOutChargeFreightotherStorageCheckoffFreightMiscellaneousChargesStorageCheckoffInElevationOutChargeFreightotherInElevationOutChargeDiscountsFreightother
922690000000000061014372018602158602167642563191927552232584968331307341840509672628262873068122661185213241367192248181900000000074061234124424074596189800000000000000016635000
```

and for the columns added to the dataframe I'm using this code snippet:

```py
cols = [i for i in new[0].unique()]
df1 = pd.DataFrame( index=range(len(cols)), columns=cols)
df1
```

Which might work, but I still need the separation of the string correctly. None of the methods I have use really seems to give me the desirable output. When I use regex, the program separates words from values, but then there is no way to map which value correspond to what word.

As always, any hint or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series.str.extractall` with capturing groups to get the word and the **numeric** value (allowing for parenthesis to indicate negative values), which are separated by a colon. Then, `pivot` this DataFrame into the appropriate format. Since the extract pairs labels with values, they can even occur out of order in separate strings, like in the sample I created below.

#### Sample data

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['Storage:9.22Checkoff:6.90InElevation:0.00OutCharge:0.00Freightother:0.00',
               'Checkoff:6.97Storage:19.22InElevation:0.00OutCharge:10.00Freightother:56.55',
               'Checkoff:(2.00)Storage:19.22InElevation:0.00OutCharge:10.00Freightother:56.55'])
```

#### Code

```
df = s.str.extractall(r'(.*?):([\(\)0-9.]+)').reset_index()
df = df.pivot(index='level_0', columns=0, values=1).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

---

```
print(df)
#  Checkoff Freightother InElevation OutCharge Storage
#0     6.90         0.00        0.00      0.00    9.22
#1     6.97        56.55        0.00     10.00   19.22
#2   (2.00)        56.55        0.00     10.00   19.22
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great @ALollz! just one quick question. I do have some values that are negative, but in the following fomat:  (2.00) that piece does not get parsed. how does the Regex will change in that case?

Comment: @WendyVelasquez you could use `r'(.*?):([\(\)0-9.]+)'` to add in the open and closing parenthesis characters to the second capturing group. I updated the example with one of these. This will work, so long as none of your labels have those characters in them. If that's a possibility you'll probably need a much more thoughtful approach.

Comment: the change you made worked :) thank you very much. now is just a matter of doing the change to a million records :D

Comment: I have a question for you, so I ran the regex and modified it a little bit: r'^(.*?):([\(\)(\,)0-9.]+)' to capture as many fields as possible. out of  46, I'm able to capture 23. the issue is some rows have NaNs, and some others don't even get picked even if they are only characters. BTW, I did see an option aggregating, but I cannot do that.

Comment: oops the expression modified is: r'^(.*?):([\(\)(\,)0-9.]+)'